# AppleGothic Font renders different on iPhone3 and iPhone4/iPod devices

Tags: iphone, fonts, render, embedded-fonts

Just realized there are big differences in the AppleGothic font on different on iPod / iPhone 3G and iPhone 4 devices.

Does anybody knows how is possible that the same embedded font renders so different?

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone 4 has a significantly higher resolution (the retina display) than previous iPhones. I would expect there to be subtle differences in glyph shape. Letters probably have smoother curves. There may also be little tracking and leading differences. But, overall, the same font should look the essentially same on different devices.

Comment: That is my question, they should look the essentially same on both devices, but they do not look essentially the same, they look very different indeed, do the test.